# how to create these two tables in one SQL command in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, create-table

I am using SQL in MS Access. I get this error:

> Syntax error in create table statement⁠⁠⁠⁠

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE school
(
     ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT ID PRIMARY KEY,
     KenyeNo INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE student
(
     ID_st INTEGER CONSTRAINT ID_st PRIMARY KEY,
     classNo INTEGER
);
```

How to create these two tables in one SQL command in MS Access?

Comment: does the answer help?

Comment: I assume you need one command per create table.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DoCmd.RunSQL` command, you can only execute one query. but you can write a simple function or procedure where you will have two commands, each for one `CREATE TABLE` query.

Try This, I've tested and it works:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE school (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, KenyeNo  INT)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE student(ID_st INT PRIMARY KEY, classNo  INT)"
```

Comment: yep, I've missed that part. BTW, Access allows only one SQL statement per query.

Comment: Kidding? what does the error say? what is your existing code?

Comment: I tested this code on blank database and it did what it had to do. Have you tried to compile and debug?

Comment: i'm working on microsoft access. Error says: Invalid SQL statement; expected "DELETE","INSERT","PROCEDURE","SELECT", OR "UPDATE"

Comment: share your code, seems you have some other problem.

Comment: CREATE TABLE school
(
     ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT ID PRIMARY KEY,
     KenyeNo INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE student
(
     ID_st INTEGER CONSTRAINT ID_st PRIMARY KEY,
     classNo INTEGER
);

Comment: I think @TedoG. multiple times explained that you can't do this in Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing it in one line of SQL, but this is what I would suggest for making a table, using SQL, in MS Access. I tried it out and it seemed to work how I think you want it to.

The main difference between what you were doing is that I replaced the second reference to the field 'ID' with MyFieldConstraint, as in the last example on this Microsoft page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177893(v=office.12).aspx

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb

dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE school " _
    & "(ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint PRIMARY KEY, " _
    & "KenyeNo INTEGER);"

dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE student " _
    & "(Id_st INTEGER CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint PRIMARY KEY, " _
    & "classNo INTEGER);"

dbs.Close
```

Hopefully this helps!